# AntiForgeryToken Error in ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I get this error - even though the AntiForgeryToken IS definitely in my view, inside a form tag:

> The required anti-forgery cookie 
>   "__RequestVerificationToken_L0NpdTpLaW5nMTZNVkM10" is not present.

**Controller**

```
/// <summary>
/// Delete 
/// </summary>
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
    // Get place from Id
    var poll = PollRepo.Select(Id);

    if (poll == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(poll);
}

/// <summary>
/// Confirm Delete
/// </summary>
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int Id)
{
    // Delete poll by Id from db
    PollRepo.Delete(Id);

    // Redirect to index
    TempData["message"] = "Poll Deleted";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Abc)
    </dd>

</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

**In generated HTML page**

```
<form action="/MyApp/MyCont/MyAct/Delete/7" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="JYMlRqNTUF6eoagnN6k7GrC1mJLKs1HDU4RCY_5_MEh2sIoJtumYEiM4LQF2BcKrf881xm-zdRU-KwBt381L9vBhuEJRLnMJY8aEgjVvdd41" />
```

When I press the delete button the error is returned.

Comment: The message is referring to the _anti-forgery **cookie**_ so it's due to the cookie not being present

Comment: One possible cause is having `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` in the `web.config.cs` file, but the project is not set to use SSL.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It was requireSSL thanks! The server requires SSL - and this flag was mistakenly set on the dev machine too.If you convert this to an answer I'll accept it thx.

Comment: I found very little on SO about this error, but I think there are other things that can cause it, and I update the answer later if I find anything. Otherwise I'll mark it as a community wiki so others can edit it with other possible causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you see relates to the anti-forgery **cookie**, not the token (the code you have shown will submit the token correctly in the request).

Other than attacks from a malicious user or something on the client causing the cookie to be deleted, one cause of this error is that your `web.config.cs` file includes

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

but you project is not set to use SSL.