# RequestVerificationToken cookie is not being sent in Ajax POST requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

Here is the Ajax code:

```
            var token = $('form input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            var data = {};
            data.Type = $(e.target).attr('type');
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = token;

            url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    //do some stuff
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    //display error
                }
            })
```

In IE 11 Developer tools, during the initial load of the page (GET), I can see that the RequestVerificationToken cookie is being set.  Also, the form element for RequestVerificationToken is being populated too.  During the Ajax POST, however, the cookie is not part of the request.

Chrome works fine in both places, and during the Ajax POST, the cookie is present.   IE 11 works locally (localhost), but this problem arises when IE 11 accesses the application on the server, and this error is returned:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L1JldkNvbm5lY3Q1" is not present.

For some reason IE 11 doesn't include the cookie in the Ajax POST when the application is on the server.  I can see that it is missing in the Network tab of IE Developer Tools.  In the Network tab of Chrome Developer tools, the cookie is present, and the POSt works.

---

ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: try making the datatype as json

Comment: I changed the return type to 'json', but the cookie still isn't making to to the controller, so the "cookie is not present" error occurs.

Comment: The error message relates to the cookie, not the token (your ajax code works fine and will send the token correctly). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054447/antiforgerytoken-error-in-asp-net-mvc-5-app/40066715#40066715) for one possible cause and solution